# Smalltalk, displaying OrderedCollection to List Widget

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

Hi I have an ordered collection of strings which I'm trying to display on a list widget.
I do the following:

```
self displayWidget list: coll.
```

where displayWidget is a List Widget and coll is the OrderedCollection containing the strings. It will display it, but it displays it in a single line.

Instead of getting

```
line one
line two
line three
```

I get:

```
line oneline twoline three
```

**I'm using visual works.***

Answer (score 1):

Inside `list:` you probably want something similar to

```
coll do: [:element | Transcript show element; cr]
```

When you send `do: [:e | ...]` to a collection it evaluates the block once for each element in the collection, each time passing the element into `element`.
Each time I'm sending `cr` to `Transcript` to add a carriage return after each element.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the collection and send withCRs message to the Strings.

Here is an simple example:

| i |

i:= 0.
[i < 5] whileTrue: [ Transcript show: 'Hello world.\' withCRs.
i := i +1.

]

withCRs method replace each \ ocurrence for a new line and carry return.

Hope it helps you.